# Subtracting 2 String Lists and Result should be stored in a New List

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have two String Lists , i want to subtract them and strore result in a new list
List_A =['A', 'B' , 'C' , 'D']
List_B =['A', 'D']

Result ['B' , 'C']

Subtracting two string lists

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score -1):

If the order of the arrays aren't important, you could implement them as sets instead and use the intersection() function.

```
x = {"A", "B", "C", "D"}
y = {"B", "C"}
z = x.intersection(y)
```

but if you want to still have them as arrays, this function will work.

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2):
    lst3 = [value for value in lst1 if value in lst2]
    return lst3
```

Comment: The second version is probably the more valuable from a learning/teaching standpoint. However, for larger data, one should convert `lst2` to a set before the repeated membership tests.

Comment: (and convert it to set **outside** of the list comprehension)